# Handle another app's obscuring keyboard on iPad split view (iOS 9 multitasking)

Tags: ios, ipad, keyboard, multitasking, splitview

Previously if one presented a keyboard on one's own app one would embed everything in a `UIScrollView` and adjust the `contentInset` to keep content from being obscured by the keyboard.

Now with split view multitasking on iOS 9 the keyboard may appear at any moment and stay visible even while the user is no longer interacting with the other app.

**Question**

Is there an easy way to adapt all view controllers that were not expecting the keyboard to be visible and without start embedding everything in scrollviews?

Comment: Were you able to find the answer to this question?

Comment: Added my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The secret is to listen to the `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame` notification that is triggered whenever the keyboard is shown/hidden from your app or from another app running side by side with yours.

I created this extension to make it easy to start/stop observing those events (I call them in `viewWillAppear`/`Disappear`), and easily get the `obscuredHeight` that is usually used to adjust the bottom `contentInset` of your table/collection/scrollview.

```
@objc protocol KeyboardObserver
{
    func startObservingKeyboard() // Call this in your controller's viewWillAppear
    func stopObservingKeyboard() // Call this in your controller's viewWillDisappear
    func keyboardObscuredHeight() -> CGFloat
    @objc optional func adjustLayoutForKeyboardObscuredHeight(_ obscuredHeight: CGFloat, keyboardFrame: CGRect, keyboardWillAppearNotification: Notification) // Implement this in your controller and adjust your bottom inset accordingly
}

var _keyboardObscuredHeight:CGFloat = 0.0;

extension UIViewController: KeyboardObserver
{
    func startObservingKeyboard()
    {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(observeKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame, object: nil)
    }

    func stopObservingKeyboard()
    {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame, object: nil)
    }

    func observeKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification(_ notification: Notification)
    {
        guard let window = self.view.window else {
            return
        }

        let animationID = "\(self) adjustLayoutForKeyboardObscuredHeight"
        UIView.beginAnimations(animationID, context: nil)
        UIView.setAnimationCurve(UIViewAnimationCurve(rawValue: (notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey]! as AnyObject).intValue)!)
        UIView.setAnimationDuration((notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey]! as AnyObject).doubleValue)

        let keyboardFrame = (notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]! as AnyObject).cgRectValue
        _keyboardObscuredHeight = window.convert(keyboardFrame!, from: nil).intersection(window.bounds).size.height
        let observer = self as KeyboardObserver
        observer.adjustLayoutForKeyboardObscuredHeight!(_keyboardObscuredHeight, keyboardFrame: keyboardFrame!, keyboardWillAppearNotification: notification)

        UIView.commitAnimations()
    }

    func keyboardObscuredHeight() -> CGFloat
    {
        return _keyboardObscuredHeight
    }
}
```

Comment: Would that spot the situation when the keyboard is already present as the app starts? if not, how did you get around that?

Comment: I call `keyboardObscuredHeight()` once on `viewWillAppear` @PeterJohnson.